# what is "arbitrary" native code in Android?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-instant-apps

In [Android Instant App documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#restricted_features), it describes one of restrictions as below;

> Run unverified software, run arbitrary native code, or load code dynamically other than the code provided by the Instant Apps runtime.

what does "arbitrary" native code mean?

Is it different from a `c-code-that-I-used-with-JNI` native code?

Comment: It means whatever code you want.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499287/android-instant-apps-can-not-run-unverified-software-run-arbitrary-native-co/

Comment: @Youngjae, i hope your problems has been solved.